# problema al listar carpeta en windows

Tags: java, lista, windows

Hola espero que me puedan ayudar mi código es este:

```
File carpeta = new File("C:/Windows/Prefetch");

File[] archivos = carpeta.listFiles();
```

El problema es que no puedo listar esta carpeta sin primero entrar manualmente y dar continuar a este error que sale cada vez que la computada es encendida.

¿Hay alguna manera de no tener que hacer es operación manual y hacerlo en java?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!